# Three.js, GLSL, HeightMaps + Alphamaps

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, heightmap

I am using three.js to attempt and learn more about OpenGL. Anyway, I've created a fragment shader which actually works for blending textures with an alphamap but I am having issues with the heightmap portion. If anyone has any ideas please let me know as I am stuck. Oh, I have used this as a reference: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_terrain_dynamic.html.

```
   <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        uniform sampler2D tDisplacement;
        varying vec2 vUv;          
        void main(void)
        {
            vUv = uv;       

            #ifdef VERTEX_TEXTURES
                vec3 dv = texture2D( tDisplacement, uv ).xyz;
                float df = 300.0 * dv.z + 1.0;
                vec3 displacedPosition = normal * df + position;        

                vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( displacedPosition, 1.0 );
                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( displacedPosition, 1.0 );
            #else
                vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            #endif

            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        }      
    </script>
    <script id="fragmentShaderNoise" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        uniform sampler2D Alpha;
        uniform sampler2D Grass;
        uniform sampler2D Stone;
        uniform sampler2D Rock;
        uniform sampler2D tDisplacement;

        varying vec3 vertex_color;
        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main(void)
        {
           vec4 alpha   = texture2D( Alpha, vUv.xy);
           vec4 tex0    = texture2D( Grass, vUv.xy * 10.0 ); // Tile
           vec4 tex1    = texture2D( Rock,  vUv.xy * 10.0 ); // Tile
           vec4 tex2    = texture2D( Stone, vUv.xy * 10.0 ); // Tile

           tex0 *= alpha.r; // Red channel
           tex1 = mix( tex0, tex1, alpha.g ); // Green channel
           vec4 outColor = mix( tex1, tex2, alpha.b ); // Blue channel

           gl_FragColor = outColor;
        }      
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problems you are having?  What is or isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

If a related example would help, I have written a demo that includes a vertex shader that incorporates displacement at:

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Fireball.html

Alternatively, perhaps you could start with something simpler, and then work incrementally towards your desired result. For example, I believe that the code below would allow you to change the vertex position according to the red amount of each pixel in the texture bumpTexture.

```
uniform sampler2D bumpTexture;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() 
{ 
    vUv = uv;
    vec4 bumpData = texture2D( bumpTexture, uv );
    float displacement = 100.0 * bumpData.r;
    vec3 newPosition = position + normal * displacement;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Those are some of the most detailed and complete examples I have been able to find on the web! Thankyou so much for all the effort! (http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/)

Comment: Also stubled across your recent work (http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Shader-Heightmap-Textures.html) which is even more relevant to this question. - Might be worth adding it to the index page :D Thanks again.